# SQL(Interbase) : Case of string with Aggregate function

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, case, interbase

I am not able to make the following SQL work in Interbase:
i get the following error:

> Error at line 1 Attempt to execute an unprepared dynamic SQL statement

SQL:

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN kl='K' THEN (SUM(DB)-SUM(CR))
   WHEN kl='L' THEN (SUM(CR)-SUM(DB))
   END AS Saldo
FROM  Table1
GROUP BY KL
```

for the `Table1` defined this way:

```
Column name   Data type
------------  ------------
KL            varchar(1)
DB            int
CR            int
```

Yet it works in [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f44a/1)

the following also works!

```
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN kl='K' THEN 1
   WHEN kl='L' THEN 2
   END as Saldo
FROM  Table1
Group By KL
```

Comment: it would help if you provide the error

Comment: @diego Added error notice + example of code that works

Comment: DB looks kind of suspicious to me as a column name.  Does Interbase of Identifier Quotes?  Also, the fiddle you posted is for MySQL, not Interbase (they don't list either Interbase of Firebird as supported).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found It!

```
SELECT Sum(CASE
       WHEN kl='K' THEN db
       WHEN kl='L' THEN cr
       END )
      -Sum(CASE
       WHEN kl='K' THEN CR
       WHEN kl='L' THEN DB
       END )

 FROM  Table1
Group By KL
```